# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lrabbitmq

Tags: rabbitmq

I have already installed rabbitmq in my system.

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lrabbitmq
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Install librabbitmq : sudo apt install `librabbitmq-dev` .... I.e. all libraries for development / compiling must be "(lib)name **-dev** "

Comment: Thank You @KnudLarse.